# Why is the Add Google Docs button hidden on some SObjects for same user?

Tags: security

We have Google apps activated.

I have a user, which can add Google docs to leads/Accounts/Oppty/etc...

[image: Button visible in Lead Object]

But when he goes to Campaign page - the buttons are missing.

[image: Buttons missing in Campaign Object]

- I only have 1 page layout for Campaigns.
- Even if I change ownership of the campaign to this user - it's still missing.
- Other user with the same profile, **has** the buttons visible
- The said profile has **Edit** options on the Campaign object

[image: Edit option for Campaign Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the "Marketing User" checkbox on **User** details to access these buttons on Campaign.